# send value on href with ajax using post method on CI

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have problem whit ajax. when i cant send a value on ajax using post method on href attribute..
this ajax my sourcecode...

```
function show_TIM(){
    var img = "<img src='"+site_url+"public/images/load.gif' align='center'>";
    $("#TIM").html(img);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"post",
        url: site_url+'index.php/controller/function/#needvaluerighthere',
        data: {
              link : $(this).attr('href'),
          },

        success:function(msg){
            $('#TIM').html(msg);
            oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    'iDisplayLength': 100
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the hmtl code is

```
<a href="'.$row['TIM_KE'].'" class="link" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".TIM" data-artid="'.$row['TIM_KE'].'" onclick="show_TIM();">
```

i try to catch $row['TIM_KE'] with ajax and send the value to the controller...
anyway, i using CodiIgniter...
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a add a click event listener, and **this** does not have a reference in the function

EVENT CALL

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    show_TIM($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

AJAX CALL

```
function show_TIM(value){
    var img = "<img src='"+site_url+"public/images/load.gif' align='center'>";
    $("#TIM").html(img);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        type:"post",
        url: site_url+'index.php/controller/function/#needvaluerighthere',
        data: {
              link : value,
          },

        success:function(msg){
            $('#TIM').html(msg);
            oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    'iDisplayLength': 100
            });
        }
    });
}
```